# mysql_connect() does connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli-multi-query

I am in a terrible situation. My PHP works with MySQL database when I use [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) connection code, but when I try to connect the database using

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
?>
```

I don't get any error message. Rather the browser just goes offline or error message. I have been trying to figure this out for two weeks.

In my PHP both MySQL and mysqli lines are uncommented. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: What error message are you getting? WHat do you mean by "browser goes offline" exactly?

Comment: "goes offline or error message". What's that error message?

Comment: Have you checked your Apache (or insert web server) log files?

Comment: thanks for the replies, i am using opera the error message is, "Connection closed by remote server" that is the error message we get when we dont have internet connection

Answer (score 1):

Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: i tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but still not working, when I use mysqli it works, problem is I cant use phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you really need to use the mysql lib? It's recommended to use mysqli and if that works, why not keep using that instead?

Comment: I really dont want to use mysqli, all i want to is to use phpmyadmin, any clue please

Comment: Is the above code all that gets executed? Or do you have other code before/after that? Another part of your code might be the issue. Try adding some `echo` statements to see which parts get executed and which don't.

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
?>

Comment: i fixed it, i just copied the libmysql to windows thanks for all your helps